# Prevent Apache AHC from adding "transfer-encoding:chunked" header to requests

Tags: apache-camel, cxf

I need to call a login API hosted @ https://login.microsoftonline.com

I am using Apache AHC v2.1  and it auto adds   http header "transfer-encoding: chunked" to all requests .

The API does not support transfer encoding and returns.

```
**Not Implemented**

HTTP Error 501. The request transfer encoding type is not supported.
```

How can I prevent AHC from adding this header ?

I have tried to use the  recommended "removeHeaders" option described  @

https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-to-avoid-sending-some-or-all-message-headers.html

But this does not remove this header .

Any help appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

If you use instead the [Apache Camel HTTP component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/http-component.html) there is a setting ***chunked*** that you can disable.

This setting is not available on *AHC* component.

Comment: Thank You @vikingsteve for confirming that AHC does not have facility to prevent this header .

Comment: No worries. Feel free to upvote the answer and accept it if you find it useful.